# Display addresses on a leaflet map in R from a .CSV

Tags: r, leaflet

My wife works with a team of people who provide in-home therapy for learning disabled kids for a school district across the city we live in.  I'm trying to create code to take in a .CSV file full of client addresses and which employee works with each one and use it to create a map that will show the geographic range of each employee.  Then when they get a new client, they could then look at the map and see which employees already work in the neighborhood of the client in order to minimize travel time.  The map I have in mind is below (they work in one city, but I'm using nation-wide cities for development) and the pasted .CSV data I'm using is also below.  I've been playing around with the code but am having trouble getting the syntax right for leaflet.  Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new the leaflet package and have mostly used R for statistics and not for visualizations like this.  Thanks!

.CSV Data (semi-colon delimited)

```
Client No.; Address; Employee;
1; Los Angeles, CA; Tom;
2; San Diego, CA; Tom;
3; Las Vegas, NV; Tom;
4; Albuquerque, NM; Tom;
5; Madison, WI; Laura;
6; Minneapolis, MN; Laura;
7; Chicago, IL; Laura;
8; Iowa City, IA; Laura;
9; Orlando, FL; Joe;
10; Mobile, AL; Joe;
11; Atlanta, GA; Joe;
12; Nashville, TN; Joe;
13; Albany, NY; Jamie;
14; Philadelphia, PA; Jamie;
15; Columbus, OH; Jamie;
```

[Example map, trying to create this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6jiP.png)

UPDATE
I made some progress, but still need to figure out the polygon addition.

```
library(leaflet)
require(RJSONIO)

geocodeAdddress_lat <- function(address) {
  require(RJSONIO)
  url <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
  url <- URLencode(paste(url, address, "&sensor=false", sep = ""))
  x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
  if (x$status == "OK") {
    out <- c(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat)
  } else {
    out <- NA
  }
  Sys.sleep(0.2)  # API only allows 5 requests per second
  out
}

geocodeAdddress_lng <- function(address) {
  require(RJSONIO)
  url <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
  url <- URLencode(paste(url, address, "&sensor=false", sep = ""))
  x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
  if (x$status == "OK") {
    out <- c(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng)
  } else {
    out <- NA
  }
  Sys.sleep(0.2)  # API only allows 5 requests per second
  out
}

mydata <- read.table("C:/Users/marast01.SJM/Documents/20170426, Leaflet     map.csv", 
                     header=TRUE, sep=",")#, row.names="id")

head(mydata)

for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  mydata$lat[i] <- geocodeAdddress_lat(mydata$Address[i])
  mydata$lng[i] <- geocodeAdddress_lng(mydata$Address[i])
}

head(mydata)

m <- leaflet(data = mydata) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(mydata$lng, mydata$lat)

m  # Print the map
```

Changing the color of the markers:

```
pal <- colorFactor(c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green"), 1:4)
pal(c(mydata$Employee))

mm <- leaflet(data = mydata) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(mydata$lng, mydata$lat, popup=mydata$Employee, 
                   color = pal(c(mydata$Employee)), fillOpacity = 0.5, stroke = FALSE)
mm
```

Comment: You may want to geocode all the address first.

Comment: Hello!  I had some time to look into it and made progress, but now am trouble having the script set a different color for each name.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question as this one is solved? (See your title)

Comment: Try using `~` in front of `pal`. The `~` tells the leaflet function to use the datasets and formulas. So you can alos replace the mydata$column with ~column.